# Changing color for each element in linerenderer not working

Tags: unity, c#

I want to change color for each line (element) just like in color switch. But my code is not working. What I wanted is that the right line should turn blue then the down line should turn color red. What is wrong with my code?

```
void Start()
{
    lineGeneratorPrefab = new GameObject();
    DrawLine();
}


private void DrawLine()
{
    GameObject myLine = new GameObject();
    myLine.transform.position = start;
    myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    lr.positionCount = 4;

    lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(-2, 0, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(2, 0, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(2, new Vector3(2, -2, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(3, new Vector3(-2, -2, 0));
    lr.materials[2].color = Color.blue;
    lr.materials[3].color = Color.red;
}
```

Comment: Are you under the impression that Unity uses a different material from the materials array for each segment of the line? To my recollection, it does not work that way: the whole multi-segment line is drawn as a whole with one material, then wholly redrawn with subsequent materials if there are multiple in the array (allowing for multi-pass effects).

Comment: @DMGregory yes thats my impression cause when I added a line renderer component on empty gameobject it says under materials you can specify the size then indicate different materials for each element.

Comment: "Element" just means an entry in the list of materials, not "segment" of the line. Have you considered using the colour gradient stops to achieve your desired colour transitions? This lets you combine as many colour changes as you have positions on your line in a single rendering pass, unlike using multiple materials.